# How can I find the hosting company URL by domain name?

Tags: hosting, dns

so I'm looking for a server host for a website that I'm building. Generally I know from continually visiting sites which ones I like and which I don't. I think this is a much better way than simply measuring ping times to determine speed.

So I want to know if there's a way to find out which hosting companies are hosting certain domains. Is this possible? whois.domaintools.com tells you certain information about the namesevers and the other about the DNS information about the host IP location. This is fine but I still don't get the website URL where I too can sign up for hosting. Often times the IP location name resolves to something really formal like XYZ Mallard Group Company LTD so this is basically useless to me. I need the hosting web URL instead.

Anyone got any ideas how I can find a domain's server hosting website url?
Thanks,
Marv

Answer (score 3):

http://www.whois.net/ Will tell you the DNS (which a lot of time has the one you can sign up for, i.e. dns.dreamhost.com points you to dreamhost.com), and it also gives you more info about the registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Finding hostnames of Ip's of server and DNS will help you to identify hosting provider